# Can we animate grid-column-start with a CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-grid

I'm trying to animate a change that happens on click via javascript, ideally without having to refactor lots of my project.

The code structure is like this:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  transition: .5s;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  transition: .5s
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the sidebar opens, my `#content` div shrinks by changing `grid-column-start` to `2`.

Adding a CSS transition to any of the elements doesn't seem to work. My question is is there a way to animate this without a big rethink of my HTML and/or CSS?

I have also have looked at animating the sidebar in with a 0fr column ([as demonstrated here](https://css-tricks.com/animating-css-grid-how-to-examples/)), but that doesn't really work with my sidebar element which is currently built as a popover contained within the grid row for layout reasons.

Comment: No - it's initial state is full width, as set in the grid-column-start and -end properties. When the sidebar is opened, it needs to shrink.

Comment: hi can you please check the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "content" div shrinks in width using transition and Javascript. The width animation doesn't work on "grid column" properity.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<style>
  #container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    transition: .5s;
  }
  
  #sidebar {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    transition: .5s;
    pointer: cursor;
  }
  
  #content {
    width: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font: 30px Helvetica;
    color: white;
  }
  
  h2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: lightgray;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <script>
    function myDiv() {
      var yourUl = document.getElementById("content");
      yourUl.style.width = yourUl.style.width === '75%' ? '10%' : '75%';

    }
  </script>

  <div id="container" onclick=myDiv()>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <h1>Click Me</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <h2>Navbar ^^</h2>

      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```